# preserve all group in regexp

Tags: regex

I have question regarding regexp, I have text like this

`embedded-software-entwickler`

basically I want to replace the `-` with something else but preserving the group so I can easily do `$1@$2@$3` with `@` as replacement of `-`

my current regexp is like this `([a-zäöüß]+)(-)` but this one will not hit the third word which is `entiwckler`

Comment: What do you mean by preserving the group?

Comment: Not sure what you are doing. Try `preg_replace('/(\p{L}+)-?/u', '$1@', $s)`. Or [`preg_replace('/\p{L}+\K-/u', "@", $str);`](https://ideone.com/8EqLlB). What is your expected output for `embedded-software-entwickler` string and why?

Comment: @Manav preserving the group meaning embedded will be group 1 software will be group 2 and entwickler will be group 3 so that when I'm going to replace it with something else I can use `$1 $2 $3`

Comment: Why not a simple `str_replace('-', '@', $string)` ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew my expected output is `embedded@software@entwickler` if I'm going to change `-` to `@` I want to understand how regexp works that is why I want to replace it using `$1@$2@$3`

Comment: @delboy1978uk yes that can be done, I've updated the tag to regexp only not doing it on php

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/Fk2cGR/1 self-explanatory

Comment: @MickyZ The question makes no sense. You say the number of hyphen separated words can be any, but your requirement is to replace with a static `$1@$2@$3` replacement.

Comment: `$1@$2@$3` for the given example which containts of 3 words.

Comment: @rndus2r if I am going to use it, it will also hit `word1!word2!word3` or `word1#word2#word3` which is should not be.

Comment: It would be at best if you would create a full example and then start trying yourself stuff. You never mentioned that before

Answer (score 2):

How about something simple like this:

```
([\w]*?)-([\w]*?)-([\w]*)
```

Replace with:

```
$1@$2@$3
```

What we did here is basically we started looking for any available character using `\w` and using the lazy sign `*?` at the beginning and the greedy sign `*` at the end to match each group, and separated each section with `-`.
[image]

If you would like to include spaces, numbers, special characters, etc. in each section, you can use something like this:

```
([\s\S]*?)-([\s\S]*?)-([\s\S]*)
```

If you prefer something dynamic, you could try something like this:

```
([^\-]+)-
```

Replace with:

```
$1@
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/p6zQTO/1/

Alternative way to mach each group plus the replacement:

```
([^\-]*)-([^\-]*)
```

Replace with:

```
$1@$2
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/p6zQTO/2/

Comment: Probably will need the u-flag to really match everything. Besides that I believe the words were used only as an example.

Comment: You're right. I added another regex to match basically everything.

Comment: this will work, but I don't want it to be static what is there are four words? like `word1-word2-word3-word4` or there are only two words `word1-word2`  and I only want letters and german umlauts

Comment: He wants to capture all "-" seperated words, you are going to miss the last one. You will need to make it greedy.

Comment: His question is misleading. He wants to capture all words, your regexp will miss the last word. This would mean 3 words in his given example, you are capturing 2. 
Your replacement is fine, but there is no difference in what OP has provided (see https://regex101.com/r/Fk2cGR/3). You will need to make the second capturing group greedy aswell to capture all words.

Comment: @rndus2r I think I found a way to do both. I updated my answer. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

If your need is simply to change all '-' into '@', trying a `tr/-/@/m` would produce simpler and better substitution.

If you need to group and extract for other purposes, then try something like `/(\w+)(?:-(\w+))*/`
(?:groups but don't extract)